# Postback to Previous Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Form.aspx page.  On Post-Back, complex validation occurs.  If there are errors found:

```
lblErrors.Text = "There are Errors"
```

You resolve whatever errors listed on the page and hit submit.  Since the Post-Back validation didn't find errors:

```
lblErrors.Text = ""
Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx")
```

On Confirm.aspx, the submitted data can be reviewed.  I have a button "Go Back to Edit"

You click the button to go back and edit something and What!?... lblErrors.Text displays "There are Errors."  I realize the Go Back functionality pulls up a Cached page, but I hoped that since I changed the Text to "" during the Form Post-Back, it would be empty when coming back.  It wasn't.

In short, I want the user to be able to post-back the previous page with all its viewstate glory.  I'll handle the lblErrors in the Page_Load at that point.

There are a lot of fields, many of which are webservice datasource drop-downs where each selection is dependent on the previous selection.  That would suck to have re-run and checked as Session variables.  So saving every field's value to variables and doing a regular redirect is not the answer I'm hoping for.  I'm expecting something about PreviousPage that I don't realize.

Comment: You will most likely have to post your errors to your Confirm.aspx page and read the Request variable containing your errors from the other page. Another option would be to validate the form client side before submitting to your server. In this case, you should also do server side validation. Don't rely on just client side validation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Cameron.  I went ahead and set up the dreaded client-side validation.  All I really did was add code so if a user changes a field that had an error, the error text dissapears.  Of course that's simple and works, but I still submit to the Confirm.aspx, then go back, and when I get back the error text is there since that's how the page last loaded (so client-side JS doesn't "stick" with the Cache of the page).  I still think I'll need a way to PostBack to the previous (Form) page.

Comment: If there are no other options, I'll move my error to my confirm page.  That doesn't sound nearly as neat or prosauce (real word, look it up) as controlling form objects in the form class.  I don't understand why, when caching for a page is disabled, the page isn't re-loaded.  It isn't an ASP.Net issue, it's just not an option in ASP.Net because browsers aren't developed to re-request a page when Back is pressed, even if No-Cache is off.  That's why I hoped ASP.Net had something I didn't know about (probably in PreviousPage or the likes) that could postback to the previous page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This defies all logic, but I don't currently care to figure out what's happening.

In my Page_Load I did this:

```
    Try
        Dim strValidation As String = String.Empty
        Dim PostbackType As String = String.Empty

        If Session("Submit") IsNot Nothing Then
            If Session("Submit").ToString = "Submit" Then
                PostbackType = "Submit"
            Else
                PostbackType = "Back"
            End If
            Session("Submit") = Nothing
        End If

        If PostbackType = "Submit" Then
            Session("Submit") = "Back"
            Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx")
        End If

        If IsPostBack AndAlso PostbackType <> "Back" Then
            If Request.Form("__EVENTTARGET").ToString.Contains("btnSubmit") Then
                strValidation = ValidateForm()
                If strValidation.Length > 0 Then
                    lblErrors.Text = strValidation
                Else
                    lblErrors.Text = ""
                    Session("Submit") = "Submit" 'Set so the page fully loads into the user's cache, then re-submits for the real submit
                    Dim jsLink As New HtmlGenericControl("script")
                    jsLink.InnerHtml = "javascript:__doPostBack('btnSearch','')"
                    jsLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript")
                    Me.Controls.Add(jsLink)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

In short, I let the page actually Load into their cache after validation, then do an immediate postback again which is for the real submit.

In long, I took the redirect out of the conditional which says the form is Validated.  Thusly, even when Validated, the page fully loads (thus going into the user's cache).  But instead, I add a Javascript to the end of the page which automatically does a postback, so all the user sees is a blink.  In that postback, my session variable says, kthx, go ahead and submit me for realz tho.  So technically, the last page their browser saw was clean.

I'd still like to hear if there is a real answer, though.  This workaround requires that Javascript is enabled on the user's PC, and also creates that "blink".

The kicker is this... When the user goes "Back" now, that jsLink Script control is still in the page... and though the page is Cached, it runs and does a Postback.  So with this, the back button actually DOES technically trigger my page_load (which I handle by skipping my Page_Load postback stuff if this is true).  But knowing this doesn't help me clean up the code.  I'd like to only use JavaScript for aesthetic reasons and not rely on it for functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into using this approach for Cross-Page posting:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.100).aspx

Something like this:

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    Label lblError = 
        (Label)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("lblError");
    if (lblError != null)
    {
        lblError.Text = "There are Errors";
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again you're a g-sauce Cameron.  Anyway, postback is originally the default asp.net function which re-loads its own page with form post values.  Cross-Page postback just means instead of reloading, you send your form post to another page if you supply a "PostBackURL" (like regular HTML does with form post target).  Though getting a connection to the previous page's controls are a good catch, I did try that.  Though I can supposedly change the value of lblError, if a user goes "back" to that page, they're still just seeing whatever they last cache'd, not what I just changed.  Poo poo.